# VS Code opens chrome debugger in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I'm running source codes on VS Code with its chrome debugger. But, whenever running the chrome debugger, the chrome browser runs in **incognito mode**. In this mode, any chrome extensions and context can't be accessible.

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this issue, not running the chrome debugger in incognito mode?

This is my VS Code chrome debugger configuration.

```
{ "configurations": [
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I was wondering too

Comment: Also with these answers, if debugger doesn't attach run vscode as Administrator or enable in Compatability settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing when I started using the VS-Code chrome debugger. But it turned out it was just **a new chrome instance**. If you truly are in incognito something is not working as it should.

I confused it with being incognito mode until I realised that it's just running with a fresh user profile w/out any extensions installed. That happens because vs-code starts chrome w/ a **custom data-dir** (which is how it should be), meaning you will have to install extensions that you had before again.

I assume this happens to prevent conflicts.

[A blog post about that from google](https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html)

As @Momia pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603558/9191773), you can disable this behaviour by disabling the `userDataDir` [configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#other-optional-launch-config-fields) like such:

```json
{ "configurations": [
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "userDataDir": false // this line disabled VSCode from running in a custom data-dir
  ]
}
```

Comment: I checked the whether a chrome was really ran on incognito mode again. On the second tries, I finally realized it was not a incognito, but it just didn't have any extensions, shortly very clean mode. If it were a real incognito mode, "incognito icon" would have been displayed in the right of address bar, but it wasn't. As you said, it's just a normal mode which doesn't have any extensions. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

To avoid incognito mode, you can set **userDataDir** to false.
You can find more info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#other-optional-launch-config-fields)

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "type": "chrome", 
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "userDataDir": false,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the code in "configurations":

```
"runtimeArgs": ["--incognito"]
```

Comment: I use chrome.exe from c:\users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\Browser\wrapper\node_modules\playwright-core\.local-browsers\chormium-930007\chrome-win  in what file do I need to put this argument in? I don't see anything that resembles a configuration file.